# Why figure resolution is decreased of levelplot() in R?

Tags: raster, r

I am using the `rasterVis` package to generate the map of GPP distribution from 2000 to 2014. The raster data is of 500 m resolution, but the output of the figure looks to have a very low resolution (I guess maybe 0.5 degree). I do not know why it happens.
The map generation code is :

```
levelplot(GPP, layout=c(5,3), 
          margin = list(draw = F),
          scales = list(cex=0.5, tck = -0.5),
          xlim = c(-3000000, 2700000), 
          ylim = c(2000000, 7000000),
          Xlab = NULL,
          ylab = NULL,
          at=seq(0,4000,40),
          par.settings=BuRdTheme())
```

The output figure is :

[image: plot]

Comment: Does it change if you give higher **maxpixels=** , such as 2e5 ?

Comment: yeah, it works when I change the maxpixels value. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Could you post your new code and outcome as your answer?

Answer (score 2):

As Kazuhito stated in the comments, the solution to this is to add the argument below to the levelplot() command. This worked perfectly for me. The maxpixels command isn't in the help document of levelplot()

```
maxpixels = 2e5
```